# C, timer_settime() error: invalid argument, after timer_delete()?

Tags: c, timer, signals, posix

I'm doing a simple program where I repeatedly create and destroy some timers; with first timer, program runs correctly, creating and destroying timers; but with second timer, when I do timer_settime(), i get error "Invalid argument"; without timer delete, only disarming timer, code runs correctly; why this?

This is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int d,x = 0;

void err_exit(char* str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void sighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    (void) sig;
    (void) uc;
    d = si->si_value.sival_int;
    ++x;
}



void handle_signal(struct sigaction* sa)
{
    sa->sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa->sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa->sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGRTMAX,sa,NULL) == -1)
        err_exit("sigaction");
}



void create_timer(struct sigevent* sev,timer_t* timer_id,int i)
{
    union sigval s;
    s.sival_int = i+11;
    printf("value: %d\n",i);
    sev->sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev->sigev_signo = SIGRTMAX;
    sev->sigev_value = s;


    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,sev,timer_id);

}


void set_timer(timer_t timer_id,struct itimerspec* ts,int j)
{
    if(ts == NULL)
        printf("itimerspec null\n");
    printf("creating timer %ju\n",timer_id);
    if (timer_settime(timer_id, 0, ts, NULL) == -1){
        printf("errno code: %d\n",errno);
        err_exit("timer_settime");
    }
}



void initialize_timerspec(struct itimerspec* ts)
{
    ts->it_value.tv_sec = 2;
    ts->it_value.tv_nsec = 5;
    ts->it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    ts->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
}



void reset_timer(timer_t timer_id,int j)
{

    printf("ok1\n");

    struct itimerspec its;
    memset((void*)&its, 0, sizeof(its));
    printf("tv_sec %d   tv_nsec %d    tv_sec2 %d   tv_nsec2 %d\n",its.it_value.tv_sec,its.it_value.tv_nsec,its.it_interval.tv_sec,its.it_interval.tv_nsec);
    printf("disarming timer  %ju\n",timer_id);
    if(timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
        err_exit("disarming timer\n");
    if (timer_delete(timer_id) == -1){
            printf("errno code: %d\n",errno);
            err_exit("timer_settime");
    }
    printf("ok2\n");

    printf("delete timer\n");
}



void* thread(void* arg)
{
    (void) arg;
    sleep(10);
    printf("awake thread\n");

    return NULL;
}





int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerspec ts[10];
    struct sigevent sev[10];
    timer_t timer_id[10];
    int j;


    handle_signal(&sa);

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        create_timer(&(sev[j]),&(timer_id[j]),j);
        initialize_timerspec(&(ts[j]));
        set_timer(&(timer_id[j]),&(ts[j]),j);
        reset_timer(timer_id[j],j);
    }

    sleep(10);

    printf("d = %d\n",d);
    printf("received signal  %d times\n",x);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Why are you set the time after you delete timer?

Comment: I'm setting fields to 0 to disarm timer; however, also without that lines program doesn't run..